# How to get the path of the opened files in DM?

Tags: automation, path, dm-script

I am trying to perform a script on all opened files in DM. For now, I have built a `Taglist` of all these files, and I am planning to use a `for statement` to get the path of each file and return it to the existing script. However, **I do not know how to extract the path of these opened files from the Taglist**. Thanks.

Comment: When dealing with lists of information, you may also want to look into Objects and ObjectLists. If you know your way around OOP coding, then they are a very versatile thing to use. Maybe not needed for your case, but I just wanted to drop that hint here as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property of a saving location is not a property of the *image* object, but of the *imageDocument* object.

The command you're seeking is

> `String ImageDocumentGetCurrentFile( ImageDocument img_doc )`
>
> Returns the file location to which the image document is currently linked.

And an example script is:

`Result("->" + GetFrontImage().ImageGetOrCreateImageDocument().ImageDocumentGetCurrentFile() )`

Comment: Related post can be found here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/69704626/1302888