# How to convert a .dm3 file (with annotation and scale bar) to .jpg/jpeg image?

Tags: export, saving-data, dm-script

I wonder how to convert a dm3 file into .jpg/jpeg images? there is test annotation and scale bar on the image. I setup a script but it always show that "the format cannot contain the data to be saved". This can be done via file/batch convert function. So how to realize the same function in script？ Thanks

```
image test:=IntegerImage("test",2,1,100,100)
test.ShowImage()
image frontimage:=GetFrontImage()
string  filename=getname(frontimage)
imagedisplay disp = frontImage.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)
disp.applydatabar()
ImageDocument frontDoc = GetFrontImageDocument() 
string directoryname, pathname
number length
if(!SaveAsDialog("","Do Not Change Me",directoryname)) exit(0)
length=len(directoryname)-16 
directoryname=mid(directoryname,0,length) 
pathname=directoryname+filename
frontDoc.ImageDocumentSaveToFile( "JPG Format", pathname )
```

Comment: mile7's answer below is correct. Essentially, you're using the wrong file-type string. There is no "JPG Format", just a "JPEG/JFIF Format". And the error message does tell exactly that. If you cite it in full, it says: "*Unrecognized file format*,or the format can not contain the data to be saved."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert to jpg you have to use `"JPEG/JFIF Format"` as the `handler` (=format).

It has to be exactly this string in the `ImageDocument.ImageDocumentSaveToFile()` function. Other formats are mentioned in the help (<kbd>F1</kbd> > Scripting > Objects > Document Object Model > ImageDocument Object > `ImageDocumentSaveToFile()` function). Those are (for example):

- 'Gatan Format'
- 'Gatan 3 Format'
- 'GIF Format'
- 'BMP Format'
- 'JPEG/JFIF Format'
- 'Enhanced Metafile Format'

---

In your code you are using the `SaveAsDialog()` to get a directory. This is not necessary. You can use `GetDirectoryDialog()` to get a directory. This saves you the name operation for the `directoryname` and avoids problems when users do change your filename.

Also for concatinating paths I prefer using `PathConcatenate()`. On the first hand this makes your code a lot more readable since its name tells what you are doing. On the other hand this also takes care of the directory ending with `\` or not and other path related things.

---

The following code is what I think you need:

```c
Image test := IntegerImage("test", 2, 1, 100, 100);
test.ShowImage();

Image frontimage := GetFrontImage();

ImageDisplay disp = frontImage.ImageGetImageDisplay(0);
disp.applydatabar();

ImageDocument frontDoc = GetFrontImageDocument();

string directoryname;
if(!GetDirectoryDialog("Select directory", "C:\\\\", directoryname)){
    //                                        ↑
    // You can of course use something else as the start point for selection here
    exit(0);
}

string filename = GetName(frontimage);
string pathname = directoryname.PathConcatenate(filename);

frontDoc.ImageDocumentSaveToFile("JPEG/JFIF Format", pathname);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly I needed and really helps me with my project. I really made a silly mistake. Thanks for your detailed instruction.

Comment: @user11078158 Please mark one of the answers as the "correct answer" by clicking the tick below the vote icons on the top left of the questions. This way the system knows that this question is answered. And others know it too when they find your question.

Answer (score 2):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69703561/1302888) is correct and should be accepted. Your problem is the wrong file-type string. You want to use **"JPEG/JFIF Format"**

---

A bit more general information on image file saving in DigitalMicrograph.

- One doesn't save *images* but always *imageDocuments* that can contain one, more, or even zero *image* objects in them. Script-commands that save an *image* like `SaveAsGatan()` really just call things like: `ImageGetOrCreateImageDocument().ImageDocumentSaveToFile()`

   The difference doesn't really matter for simple one-image-in-document type images, but it can make a difference when there are multiple images in a document, or when a single image is displayed multiple times simultaneously (which can be done.) So it is always good to know what "really" goes on.
- *ImageDocuments* contain some properties relating to saving:

  - A **save format** (“Gatan Format”, “TIFF Format”, …)

    - *Default value*:  What it was opened with, or last used save-format in case of creation
    - *Script commands*: 
      `ImageDocumentGetCurrentFileSaveFormat()` 
       `ImageDocumentSetCurrentFileSaveFormat()`
  - A current **file path**:

    - *Default value*:  What it was opened from, or empty
    - *Script commands*: 
      `ImageDocumentGetCurrentFile()` 
       `ImageDocumentSetCurrentFile()`
  - A **dirty-state**:

    - *Default value*: clean when opened, dirty when created
    - *Script commands*:
       `ImageDocumentIsDirty()` 
       `ImageDocumentClean()`
  - A **linked-to-file state**:

    - *Default value*: true when opened, false when created
    - *Script commands*: 
      `ImageDocumentIsLinkedToFile()`
- There are **two ways** of saving an *imageDocument*:

  - Saving **the current document itself** to disc:

    `void ImageDocumentSave( ImageDocument imgDoc, Number save_style )`
     This utilizes the current properties of the *imageDocument* to save it to current path in current format, marking it clean in the process.
     The `save_style` parameter determines how the program deals with missing info:

    - 0 = never ask for path
    - 1 = ask if not linked (or empty path)
    - 2 = always ask
  - Saving **a copy of the current document** to disc:

    `void ImageDocumentSaveToFile( ImageDocument imgDoc, String handler, String fileName )`
     This makes a copy and save the file under provided path in the provided format. The *imageDocument* in memory does not change its properties. Most noticeable: It does *not* become clean, and it is *not* linked to the provided file on disc.
     The `filename` parameter specifies the saving location *including* the filename. If a *file extension* is provided, it has to match the file-format, but it can be left out.
     The `handler` parameter specified the file-format and can be anything GMS currently supports, such as:

    - `Gatan Format`
    - `Gatan 3 Format`
    - `GIF Format`
    - `BMP Format`
    - `JPEG/JFIF Format`
    - `Enhanced Metafile Format`

---

### In short:

To save the currently opened *imageDocument* with a different format, you would want to do:

```c
imageDocument doc = GetFrontImageDocument()
doc.ImageDocumentSetCurrentFileSaveFormat("TIFF Format")
doc.ImageDocumentSave(0)
```

While to just save a copy of the current state you would use:

```c
imageDocument doc = GetFrontImageDocument()
string path = doc.ImageDocumentGetCurrentFile() // full path including extension!
path = PathExtractDirectory(path,0) + PathExtractBaseName(path,0) // path without file extension
doc.ImageDocumentSaveToFile("TIFF Format", path )
```

Comment: Really thanks for your detailed instructions. These information helps me solve a lot of puzzles I had been having. I was not familiar with parameters of these functions. Again, thanks a lot.