# Is there a function for reading file location from a file open in DM

Tags: image, path, dm-script

Is there a function for reading "file location" from an image open in DM?
Under ImageInfo/Image/Info, at the bottom of the window, I can read the path under "File location".

Can I use a script call to grab that info as full path - and what is the function call?

Thanks,
Edgar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Note, however, that it is the *ImageDocument* that is tied to a file, not an *Image*. As such, the command is method of the ImageDocument object.

> `String ImageDocumentGetCurrentFile( ImageDocument img_doc )`

A typical script would be like:

```c
imageDocument doc = GetFrontImage().ImageGetOrCreateImageDocument()

if ( doc.ImageDocumentIsLinkedToFile() )
    Result("\n File of current front image:" + doc.ImageDocumentGetCurrentFile())
else
    Result("\n Current front image is not linked to a file.")
```

---

You may also find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69704626/1302888) useful.